# Shortcut to the Windows 11 context menu item

Tags: windows-11, context-menu

I prefer working with a keyboard and opening context menus using shortcuts. In Windows 11, I can open the context menu with Shift+F10. However, I'd also like to select a menu item using a shortcut. It seems that shortcut keys are displayed for the majority of menu items, except for the one I use the most:

[image]

How can I add option to select "Run with PowerShell" with some key press?

Comment: Not sure about native Windows `explorer.exe` but I think one of the AHK showcase scripts could potentially work for you?  I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Windows 11 does not natively offer what you want, so you will need to take your chances with 3rd party offerings.  I just type a few characters in the Start Search section and get what I want.

Comment: As @John states, for a submenu (e.g., *Send To >*), typing a letter or two selects an item. In the main context menu, the up and down keys navigate, and Enter selects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open regedit, select Computer in tree,
press Ctrl+F to get search box,
tick all 4 values,
search for "Run with PowerShell"

Once you locate it add "&" in front of letter you wish to use for keybind.
So if you want letter P, you should change "Run with PowerShell" to "Run with &PowerShell";

[image]

For letter T, set as "Run wi&th PowerShell", T2 means i'll have to press T two times to select it...
[image]

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much. Just an annoying thing is that "&" disappears from time to time, and I need to reset it.